# In Ubuntu, how is my environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` empty, even though `ldd mybinary` clearly finds paths?

Tags: snap, environment-variables, qt, dynamic-linking, ld

I am trying to build my own local application. Because `snapcraft` lacks `qbs` support, I am trying to develop my own passive support for qbs.

Anyway, just stepping through this, in QtCreator, qbs projects allow for an install option:

[image]

And here is what I got QBS doing so far:

```
$ tree ./bin
./bin
└── category-scraper

0 directories, 9 files
$ tree ./lib
./lib
├── libqconsoletoolkit.so
├── libqnetworktoolkit.so
├── libqparsingtoolkit.so
├── libqsnappytoolkit.so
└── libqunicodetoolkit.so

0 directories, 15 files
```

When I run the application:

```
$ ./bin/category-scraper 
./bin/category-scraper: error while loading shared libraries: libqnetworktoolkit.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Which makes sense because `ldd` says:

```
$ ldd bin/category-scraper 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe23b57000)
    libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5 => /home/akiva/Programming/Qt/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5 (0x00007f843ca44000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /home/akiva/Programming/Qt/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f843c200000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /home/akiva/Programming/Qt/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f843be6b000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/akiva/Programming/Qt/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f843b711000)
    libqnetworktoolkit.so => not found
    libqunicodetoolkit.so => not found
    libqparsingtoolkit.so => not found
    libqconsoletoolkit.so => not found
    libqsnappytoolkit.so => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f843b388000)
```

What baffles me is this:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

produces nothing, and the environment variable did not even exist until I tried manually setting it... which also did not work.

Why is this environment variable empty, and how is ldd linking without this variable, and what can I do to make it so it finds the `.so` files I define?

Thanks.

Comment: The default library paths are defined in `/etc/ld.so.conf` and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`. This config is then used by `ldconfig` to populate `/etc/ld.so.cache` with a compiled list of all available libraries. See `man ldconfig` for more info.